# django project import issue with mod_wsgi when deploy to apache server

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

Am in a problem when deoply my django web app to local apache server,**its worked in Development server**. My project name is 'DjangoApis'
project's structure : home/ji/Desktop/testcloud/DjangoApis/

```
__init__.py
  django.wsgi
  settings.py
  manage.py
  urls.py 
  mywebapp
       --> __init__.py
       --> static
       --> templates
       --> urls.py
       --> views.py
  myapis ( create it as a project itself)
       --> __init__.py
       --> manage.py
       --->....
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (        
    'DjangoApis.mywebapp',
    'DjangoApis.myapis',
)
```

**django.wsgi:**

**

```
import os
import sys
path = '/home/ji/Desktop/testcloud.aws'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)   
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoApis.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**

**urls.py** in Project folder(DjangoApis):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^api/', include('DjangoApis.myapis.url')),
  (r'^', include('DjangoApis.mywebapp.urls')),      
)
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
 VirtualHost *:80
        ServerName test.webapp
        DocumentRoot /home/ji/Desktop/testcloud/DjangoApis

        <Directory /home/ji/Desktop/testcloud/DjangoApis>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory> 
        WSGIDaemonProcess test.webapp processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup test.webapp 
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ji/Desktop/testcloud/DjangoApis/django.wsgi

    /VirtualHost
```

when I run in browser< I got Internal Server Error.
    error log:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
[Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     app = import_module(appname)
[Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
```

> [Thu Dec 08 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]
>   TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module
>   named myapis

```
[Thu Dec 08 17:56:46 2011] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Thu Dec 08 17:56:46 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2rc1.
[Thu Dec 08 17:56:46 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2+.
[Thu Dec 08 17:56:46 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2+ configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Note: Am using django piston.Please help me to rectify the problem,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to: 1) add manage.py to project directory 2) use full path to your apps - DjangoApis.mywebapp, DjangoApis.myapis

Comment: @skyfox manage.py already there am sorry to specify that,I tried DjangoApis.mywebapp, DjangoApis.myapis,it also not working,Now I got the Django default error page with message,ImportError at /

No module named mywebapp.urls,[previously I got apache's error page(I think )] And also Iadded improt mywebapp to project's urls.py file

Comment: apache error log has no any indication of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
sys.path.append('/home/ji/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis')
```

That you need to add both parent directory and project directory is documented in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

Comment: I edited django.wsgi as you suggested,But I don't know am still facing the problem. If I comment the line (r'^', include('mywebapp.urls')), in Project's urls.py there is no error.Also I added import DjangoApis.mywebapp in the file

Comment: Is myapis directory actually readable to user that your application runs as under Apache.

Comment: Yea myapis readable and its runs under apache, Now shows the error 'ImportError at /

No module named mywebapp'

Comment: what is the correct way to import an app's url in project?                                         url(r'^appurl',include(project.app.urls)) is it correct?               import project.app or from project.app import urls which one is the correct way?

Comment: Not only adding sys.path.append('/home/ji/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis') solves the problem. Use as below                  import DjangoApis.mywebapp
from  DjangoApis.mywebapp.urls import *                             (r'^', include('project.app.urls')),[also add 'projectname.app' in installed apps in settings file ]

Comment: Thanks @Graham Dumpleton,now mysite loading using mod_wsgi,Now I have a problem with my sttaic files,can you look the statckoverflow link and suggest what I am missing http://stackoverflow.com/q/8456083/658976

Comment: now django tries to load /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs, instead of /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/static/js