# issue in loading static contents in django1.3+mod_wsgi+apache2

Tags: django, apache, static, mod-wsgi, django-1.3

I am facing  problem with static files(Django1.3) when tried to deploy it in my local apache server(apache2+mod_wsgi), the ***problem only for the static contents*** other parts ok[its worked in the devlopment server].

My project now in a folder 'testcloud' in Ubandu Desktop,My project
name is DjangoApis,Following is my project structure:
Desktop->testcloud:

```
DjangoApis
        ...
         mywebapp
                static
                templates
                templatetags
                urls.py
                views.py
         myapis
              .....
Settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/
teststaticfiles/'
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\
\','/'),
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'DjangoApis.mywebapp',
   'DjangoApis.myapis',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static').replace('\
\','/'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

/etc/apache2/sites/enabled/DjangoApis:

> ```
> Alias /favicon.ico /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/
> static/favicon.ico
> AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/
> DjangoApis/static/styles/$1
> Alias /static/ /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/static/
> <Directory /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/static>
> Order deny,allow
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/
> django.wsgi
> ```

apache errorlog:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:36 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:36 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:36 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:36 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs,
referer: http://test.testapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://test.webapp/
[Sat Dec 10 03:16:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
exist: /home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticimages,
referer: http://testwebapp/
```

errorlog of firebug:

```
test.webapp (line 62)
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://test.webapp/css/styles/index.css/"
/css/s...ex.css/
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.webapp/static/images/logo.jpg"
logo.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.webapp/static/images/line.jpg"
line.jpg
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.webapp/static/images/banner_phone.jpg"
.........................
```

**Note** I used collectstatic command.
Please help me to solve the issue,Thanks in advace.

Comment: @Nagisa,I don't know why it happens ,Now templates in a way {{STATTIC_URL}}css/styles/index.css,I aslo tried {{STATTIC_URL}}/css/styles,it also create the same errors.

Comment: Now my static files and templates are inside app and not in the root folder of the project.Is it create any problem?

Comment: well I solved the problem,its because of a mistake I made to map the static file directory in apache config

Comment: Well, then I moved my comments to answer. Accept it so issue would appear as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely, Apache tries to load files from `/home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/staticjs`, not `/home/jisson/Desktop/testcloud.aws/DjangoApis/static/js` like you wanted.

If files are correctly collected by collectstatic command (they appear in STATIC_ROOT directory after running that command), then problem is not in Django side, but rather in Apache, so you should check your Apache configuration files.